# std::vector and polymorphism

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Deriv : public Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Deriv(){}
};

void f(Base *){
  cout << "f(Base *)" << endl;
}

void f(vector<Base *>){
  cout << "f(vector<Base *>)" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  Deriv *d = new Deriv;
  vector<Deriv *> v;
  v.push_back(d);

  f(d); // works
  //f(v); // does not compile
  return 0;
}
```

The first f() works, but the second gives a compile time error:

> `f(vector<Deriv *>) not found.`

My question: is there a way to make it work: some kind of polymorphism with vectors?

Answer (score 4):

The property you want is called covariance. And the answer is no, you cannot do this: vectors are not covariant.

The canonical example of why this is not allowed goes like this:

```
class Deriv2 : public Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Deriv2(){}
};

void f(vector<Base *>& v){
  v.push_back(new Deriv2); // oops, just pushed a Deriv2 into a vector of Deriv
}
```

If you're not adding elements to the vector, you can just pass a pair of *input* iterators. Passing output iterators would not work either.

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void f(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

f(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: probably worth highlighting that this applies to all containers not just vectors..(?)

Comment: @Tomalak: no, it's not about templates in general. You can write covariant templates for things that are really covariant. The language lacks direct support for it, though.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK not the way you would like (`vector<Base*>` is a fundamentally different type to `vector<Deriv*>`).

Here's one alternative approach - this is of course a general algorithm

```
template <typename Iterator>
void f(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  // now do stuff...
}
```

To call

```
f(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: +1 the solution is to make f a template (and preferably one with an algorithm like signature as you have done)

Answer (score 1):

You should write this in main

```
  Deriv *d = new Deriv;
  vector<Base *> v;  // Correction
  v.push_back(d);
```

You can still push the `Derived` objects into container and `f()` works fine.

Template solution is good as well:

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::vector<T>);
```

Comment: I mean, this does not answer the question. The OP isn't struggling with polymorphism on `Base`/`Derived`; the OP wants to send `std::vector<Derived*>` to a function expecting `std::vector<Base*>` (and/or, I suppose, the other way around).

Comment: Making `v` a `std::vector<Base*>` _is_ a good idea, but I don't think that this is the direction the OP is asking about.

Comment: Ah, that. Anyway, I think it's better to create a container with base pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`Base` and `Deriv` are covariant types, but `std::vector<Base*>` and `std::vector<Deriv*>` are not covariant types.

When `X` is an object of a covariant type `B`,  you can assign object of any type `D` derive from `B`, to `X`. That is what happens in your first case.